# PDO and CodeIgniter - is it secure?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, pdo

I dont have any previous experience with PDO, so my question may sound too simple.
I heard few times that PDO is better than mysql/mysqli in terms of security ,and since Codeigniter is supporting PDO driver, I decided to make the change in my new project.

but as I'm aware of Codeingiter doesn't use prepared statements, and (I think) it missed the point of using PDO, is that correct, and is it insecure?
So my question: is using PDO driver with codeigniter considered insecure?
And, does that mean I must take care of the basic security by myself?

Comment: nothing is ever secure, just as secure as it can be. it is down to you to learn, understand and implement security. a library or language will only provide the foundations. in short yes it is 'secure' but you can make holes.

Comment: @TomIngram You're right, but I meant is PDO with codeigniter is secure just like mysql with codeigniter?

Comment: @itachi I'm talking about mysql_* not MySQL itself, please don't misunderstand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All query calls are escaped in the simplified `$this->db` functions, such as `delete()` and `get_where()`. This adds some automated security.

If written too slobby, you may grant access to users to edit other users content for instance. So there's no magical solution to full security. The more detailed you are, the more correct your code will work for you.

If you need custom queries, you can do like this:

```
$int_user_id = 1;

$this->db->query("
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = ?
", array($int_user_id));
```

**Note:** To implement `IN ()` and `LIKE`, you need to escape accordingly, and not insert through `array()` and `?`.

[**query()**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)
[**escape()**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html)

Comment: so if I use PDO or mysqli_,the same "basic" security is implemented since Codeigniter is escaping the input by using it's own unique way, right?

Comment: CodeIgniter escapes parsed values, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Database Support
```

The core advantage of PDO over MySQL is in its database driver support. PDO supports many different drivers like CUBRID, MS SQL Server, Firebird/Interbase, IBM, MySQL, and so on.

```
 2. Security
```

Both libraries provide SQL injection security, as long as the developer uses them the way they were intended. It is recommended that prepared statements are used with bound queries.

```
 3. Speed
```

While both PDO and MySQL are quite fast, MySQL performs insignificantly faster in benchmarks – ~2.5% for non-prepared statements, and ~6.5% for prepared ones.

Answer (score -1):

From what I know (CodeIgniter newbie ;)) it takes care of security pretty well with ActiveRecords. I don't know if it's using PDO or not, but it's pretty darn easy to use, queries look really clean, and it has query caching.

Comment: Just a note, codeigniter doesn't use activerecord. What it uses is query builder.

Comment: I used this (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) as a source. You're right, I added an extra 's' ;)

Comment: Don't fool yourself with their publicity. They are misleading the users.  Know the active record management principles. Look at how the active record is used in yii. CI has just a query builder. Far from active record (s)

Comment: In that case - thank you very much for info! I'll have to reconsider using CI.